# Is it a good idea to have a web socket server under a private network?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have used Web Sockets in several projects but I always build something with the following architecture: Web Socket (WS) server in a server with a public IP and a WS client as a web client without a public available IP.

Due to a system I am working on now it would be useful to have a IoT Web Socket server in any local network that external clients would connect to. I was planning to have a list of IP addresses in a available (publicly IP) server that would let me know what is the IP of each device.

Has someone tried something like that?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking.  You can certainly have a websocket server on a private network, but it would most likely be used for connections made from that private network.  To connect to a server on a private network from the outside public network, you would have to punch some sort of hole in the firewall and you'd have to create some sort of public IP address that is forwarded to your server on the private network.  In a home network this would typically be done with port forwarding configuration in the home router.

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking (I am trying to have multiple WS servers in private IPs). Port forwarding seems to be the way to go if we want to reach a private IP WS servers. Thanks!